# Accessing a C++ .lib library from c#

Tags: c#, c++, dll

I have a c++ library file (.lib). How can I access the functions within it from C#? I have read that I could wrap the library file in a c++ dll and expose the functions that way. Is that the only way? I am not the owner of the code, so my options are limited.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Wrap the C++ lib with a C++/CLI assembly.

C++/CLI allows you to mix managed and unmanaged code, serving as a bridge between C# and native C++.   It's actually very straightforward and relatively easy to do, although it can get tedious if you have a lot of classes/functions to wrap.

[Here](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/sasha/archive/2008/02/16/net-to-c-bridge.aspx) is one example.

Comment: Thank you. This is the approach I will use since I cannot modify the original c++ library.

Answer (score 1):

You can not access a c++ library file (.lib) directly. The best way is to have an unmanaged wrapper around your unmanaged code. Reference [`DllImportAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.dllimportattribute.aspx).

There's a good example of it's usage in the MSDN help document:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

class Example
{
    // Use DllImport to import the Win32 MessageBox function.
    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    public static extern int MessageBox(IntPtr hWnd, String text, String caption, uint type);

    static void Main()
    {
        // Call the MessageBox function using platform invoke.
        MessageBox(new IntPtr(0), "Hello World!", "Hello Dialog", 0);
    }
}
```

---

Also note: You can have a managed c++ wrapper around your c++ library, but it's better to write your wrapper in unmanaged c++ code.

Comment: DllImport can import *.lib? I did not know that :)

Comment: Yea, my answer was a bit hasty. I read c++ and instantly thought he meant a compiled assembly. I missed the .lib part because some people use the term library similarly to assembly.